# Extract certain information from json into csv

Tags: python, json

I have a json file that look like this:

```
{
  "issueInfo" : [ {
  "cid" : 494960,
  "occurrences" : [ {

    "file" : "/components/applications/diag/_common/src/diag_il.c",
    "function" : "diag_il_u8StopLoopbackMicIn",

    "mainEventLineNumber" : 6018,
    "mainEventDescription" : "Assigning value \"10\" to \"u8ResData\" here, but that stored value is overwritten before it can be used.",

  } ],
  "triage" : {

    "classification" : "Unclassified"
  },  
}
```

I want to extract out the information like cid, firstDetectedDateTime, file, function, mainEventLineNumber, mainEventDescription and classification. All of these information needed will be put into a csv file. The following is my coding:

```
import csv
import json
with open ("a.log","r") as file:
    data=json.load(file)
f=csv.writer(open("test.csv", "w", newline=''))
f.writerow(["cid", "firstDetectedDateTime", "file", "function",
"mainEventLineNumber", "mainEventDescription", "classification"])
for data in file:
f.writerow(data["issueInfo"]["cid"],
          data["issueInfo"]["firstDetectedDateTime"],
          data["issueInfo"]["occurrences"]["file"],
          data["issueInfo"]["occurrences"]["function"],
          data["issueInfo"]["occurrences"]["mainEventLineNumber"],
          data["issueInfo"]["occurrences"]["mainEventDescription"],
          data["issueInfo"]["triage"]["classification"])
```

The error shown after I run the command is :

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Anyone can help me to solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: The json you posted is not properly formatted

Answer (score 1):

Check the type of `data` (It must be a dictionary). Also, there is an invalid key error `firstDetectedDateTime`.

Try this,

```
import csv
import json
with open ("a.log","r") as file:
    data=json.load(file)
f=csv.writer(open("test.csv", "w", newline=''))
f.writerow(["cid", "firstDetectedDateTime", "file", "function","mainEventLineNumber","mainEventDescription", "classification"])
f.writerow([data["issueInfo"][0]["cid"],
      "",
      data["issueInfo"][0]["occurrences"][0]["file"],
      data["issueInfo"][0]["occurrences"][0]["function"],
      data["issueInfo"][0]["occurrences"][0]["mainEventLineNumber"],
      data["issueInfo"][0]["occurrences"][0]["mainEventDescription"],
      data["issueInfo"][0]["triage"]["classification"]])
```

Output CSV looks like,

```
cid,firstDetectedDateTime,file,function,mainEventLineNumber,mainEventDescription,classification
```

`494960,,/components/applications/diag/_common/src/diag_il.c,diag_il_u8StopLoopbackMicIn,6018,"Assigning value ""10"" to ""u8ResData"" here, but that stored value is overwritten before it can be used.",Unclassified`

If the page contains many JSON sets eg:`data_sets` here, Keep the headers fixed only change the portion below that.

```
for data in data_sets:
    f.writerow([data["issueInfo"][0]["cid"],
    "",
    data["issueInfo"][0]["occurrences"][0]["file"],
    data["issueInfo"][0]["occurrences"][0]["function"],
    data["issueInfo"][0]["occurrences"][0]["mainEventLineNumber"],
    data["issueInfo"][0]["occurrences"][0]["mainEventDescription"],
    data["issueInfo"][0]["triage"]["classification"]])
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, how about if my json file contain many sets of this information and I need to extract all it out. How I can do that?

Comment: how is the coding should be look like? can I just add a for loop coding on the above f.writerow([data["issueInfo"][0]["cid"], ?

Comment: Thanks Arun, your help was much appreciated.

Comment: Hi Arun, can I know why should we add a [0] into our coding? Thanks

Comment: `[0]` means we are fetching the first element of the list. In this case `data["issueInfo"]` is a list of dictionaries. In order to get a dictionary, we fetch that way.

Answer (score 0):

The json library in python can parse JSON from strings or files. The library parses JSON into a Python dictionary or list

json.loads() function parses the json string data and it can be used as a normal dictionary in python. And we can access the values using keys.

import json
    import csv

```
employee_data = '{"employee_details":[{"employee_name": "James", "email": "james@gmail.com", "job_profile": "Sr. Developer"},{"employee_name": "Smith", "email": "Smith@gmail.com", "job_profile": "Project Lead"}]}'
employee_parsed = json.loads(employee_data)
emp_data = employee_parsed['employee_details']

# open a file for writing
employ_data = open('..../EmployData.csv', 'w')

# create the csv writer object
csvwriter = csv.writer(employ_data)
count = 0
for emp in emp_data:
      if count == 0:
             header = emp.keys()
             csvwriter.writerow(header)
             count += 1
      csvwriter.writerow(emp.values())
employ_data.close()
```

Comment: Hi! I edited your answer, so that code is formatted correctly. Would you please add some text, to explain your logic and your solution?

Comment: Please add explanation to your answer, not to comments. ;) Answers should contain all it's needed to understand it, not only a chunk of code.